# Should I return to a company that let me go during the pandemic?

Tags: career-development

I worked as an intern at a local Fortune 500 company for a year when the pandemic hit in March. I loved working there, even though the environment was a little cut-throat. They verbally promised me a job upon graduation in May. However, the COVID-19 virus was still running rampant, and the company was on a hiring freeze and therefore could not formally extend me a job offer.

I understood why they couldn't hire me at the time, and put my resume on the market, and was quickly employed by another large corporation. I've been at my new company for just under 1 year now, and it's been good, but I'm not as passionate about my new job as I was with my in the old company. I applied and was accepted into the company's development program, which starts in June. The development program is a rotational opportunity to be in several different departments over the period of three years, graduating to a manager-level position.

This week, the old company's vice president gave me a call wanting me to come back to the old company. It's for a job that is tailored to me, and they'll double my salary.

Should I take the new job for more money and leave the development program? Or should I stay with the company that has invested so much in me?

Comment: Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision.

Comment: You should probably change your user name to something more anonymous. You may not want your old, current, or future employers to see your questions here.

Comment: The development program should be quite valuable for your career. If you go back to the old company, make sure you get something that puts you on a similar track. I don't see why you shouldn't discuss this openly with your contact from the old company. An F500 VP can probably make it happen.

Comment: We can't make your choice for you. They didn't let you go. They didn't extend a job offer due to the pandemic. That's not the same as being let go and that's not a ding on their part. It's completely understandable.

Comment: So the company that you loved to work for wants you back, and doubles you salary, why would you not want to go back?

Comment: So you go back to the old company for the double salary and 2 months later they let you go again. Can you trust them?

Comment: @Zebra12 If you can get on an actual contract that promises such things, (wage and whatever, plus maybe something similar to your program you’re on now) go for it. Life is beyond too short to worry about not following your passion…just don’t get sucked up into obsession of work. Make sure you save money for the day the company decides to get rid of you or the pandemic gets worse. On top of that, keep in mind the company you have now, may promote you to a much higher position later in life, giving you maybe new undiscovered passions, and a higher wage than the ‘double’ you may get now.

Answer (score 0):

I have two mantra's in my life that speak to your dilemma, told to me by a very wise mentor at work: 1) Be careful where you lean your ladder, and 2) Never look back.

I would also be skeptical on them offering to double your salary. Another saying that may apply there is "easy come, easy go". Then again, if you stick with your new role, you might outgrow the doubled salary.

You could advantage of the opportunities in your current role, and since you enjoyed it, you can offer to come back to the old company with managerial experience later on - at the normal salary that you know you can get.

On the other hand, you should always follow your passion.